# Unlock Google Spreadsheet by Calling a Web App

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, web-applications, google-sheets, http-status-code-401

I am bulding a sales spreadsheet with Google Sheets and I need that the users can unlock certain range of cells by clicking on "Edit" button, so they can edit an existing sale. The problem is that the users don't have authorization for change protected cells and therefore the script can't unlock the cells when runned by them. So I need that any user is able to unprotect the sheet running the script as me, the author.

The solution I have been trying for two days is to deploy a script as web app that unlock the cells, executed as me, and reach its URL from another script, so the user would unlock the cells indirectly using my credentials. What I did:

1. Created a doPost function with the code to unlock the cells:

```js
function doPost() {
  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var ss = app.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/[SPREADSHEET_ID]');
  var activeSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Create-Edit Sales');
  
  //change cells' color to white
  activeSheet.getRange('A5:B5').setBackground('#ffffff');
  
  //remove cells' protection
  var allProtections = activeSheet.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);
  var matchingProtections = allProtections.filter(function(existingProtection) {
  return existingProtection.getRange().getA1Notation() == 'A5:B5';
  });
  var protection = matchingProtections[0];
  protection.remove();
}
```

2. Deployed the above script as web app which gave me a https://script.google.com/macros/s/[WEB_APP]/exec URL.
3. Finally I created a function that would be triggered when the user press the "Edit" button. Then this function would call the web app using its URL and my project credentials:

```js
function UnlockCells(form) {
  var CLIENT_ID = 'CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com';
  var CLIENT_SECRET = 'CLIENT_SECRET';
  var url = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/[WEB_APP]/exec";
  
  var options = {  
    headers: {"Authorization": "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode(CLIENT_ID + ':' + CLIENT_SECRET)},
    method: "post",
    payload: form, //don't know what to use in payload
  }
  
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  Logger.log('responseCode: ' + response);//View the Logs
}
```

When I run the UnlockCells function, I get the following message:

`Request failed for https://script.google.com/macros/s/[WEB_APP]/exec returned code 401. Truncated server response: <!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head><meta name="description" content="Web word processing, presentations and spreadsheets"><meta name="viewport" c... (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response) (line 461, file "Sales Scripts")`

For what I've searched in web, this error 401 has to do with an authentication problem, but I reviewed all of my OAuth and API's configurations and couldn't find the problem.

**NOTE: if I change the doPost function to doGet and access the web app URL from any browser, the script in doGet function is executed correctly and the cells in  the sheet became unlocked.

Am I in the right direction? What would be the best way of doing so?

Best regards, thanks!

Comment: Try visiting `https://script.google.com/macros/s/[WEB_APP]/exec` and viewing the response in your web browser; it is likely Google's authorization prompt.

Comment: When I do that, the script is executed perfectly. The only message I get is "The script completed but did not return anything." as the function has no return, but everything goes right.

Comment: [Make it return something](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)

Comment: I would do the editing with the webapp and that way you don't have to protect the Spreadsheet at all.

Comment: You didn't say anything about deployment auth config.  Who is web-app deployed to "run as" and "who can access"? Under whose authorization does the `UnlockCells` run as? Basic authorization simply won't work in any case- you'd need oauth.

Comment: The WebApp was deployed to "run as me" and to be accessed by "anyone". UnlockCells runs under my authorization. Already configured OAuth, but I think that's not enough. If I test the API in the Google library, I can get (read) and update (write) the protected cells. Am I passing these OAuth authentication correctly in the code or do I need more details to be passed in the UrlFetch?

Comment: I don't think you're passing oAuth correctly. `Authorization": "Basic " + Uti` should be something like `Authorization": "Bearer " + oauthtoken`(not id: secret). You should Use `@` to notify us like `@TheMaster` or `@Cooper`